# Disable right-clicking on an embedded livestream flash object?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, embed, right-click

I'm currently running an embedded Flash swf object on my site.  I'd like to prevent people from right-clicking on it.  Problem is that I don't have access to original swf, so I can't add an AC3 script, and I want to avoid using JavaScript to do so.  People can still disable Java to get what they want.

So my question is, is there anyway to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Load the SWF into a new SWF, and from there disable the right-click.

```
// Load SWF
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("ExternalSWF.swf");
myLoader.load(url);
addChild(myLoader);   

// Disable Right-Click
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK, function(e:Event){});
```